# jQuery Responsive only works on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, controller

Why won't this work on page load when I'm using mobile? It only works on resize.

```
var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
jQ(document).ready(function($) {
  resizeController();
  jQ(window).resize(resizeController);
});

function resizeController() {
  var screenwidth = window.innerWidth;
  if (screenwidth <= 533) {
  jQ('.catalog-category-view .col-main .block-layered-nav').detach().appendTo(jQ('.footer'));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `load()` method:

```
var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
jQ(document).ready(function($) {
  resizeController();
  jQ(window).resize(resizeController);
  jQ(window).load(resizeController);//When loaded execute also the function
});
```

Comment: It works. Thanks,  But what's the point in calling it as "resizeController();" in the first line of the ready function then?

Comment: @RonV `.ready` executes when the DOM is ready (all elements are found and ready to be used)  `.load()` executes when the page is fully loaded (everything is in place + the content).